# Error : File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found. }

Tags: latex, tex, miktex

I am trying to compile a .tex document into a pdf in TexStudio (and I have also tried in MikTex) and the following error is outputted `File l3backend-pdfmode.def not found`. I have tried downloading 13backend package but no luck. Do I need to place the package in a specific folder?

Comment: Can you add a small test document that reproduces the error and the .log file?

Comment: Just a note, I found this error while using Rstudio and Rmarkdown, but I used `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()` as suggested in the error messages I got in the console and it worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, turned out my miktex library was out-of-date

I opened "miktex console" and updated it.

Answer (score 1):

I incurred into the same issue slightly after an upgrade from Debian 10 to Debian 11. For me, removing all the `.texlive*` directories from my home folder solved it

```
mv ~/.texlive* /tmp # If you want to restore them later
rm -r ~/.texlive* # If you are sure about deleting
```

The `~/.texlive2020` directory was rebuilt after running `pdflatex`.